# Trouble installing lalsuite package in python 3

Tags: python, anaconda, package, python-wheel, installation-package

I am having trouble installing a package in python 3, the package is lalsuite, its a package from LIGO for physics stuff.
I have tried everything I could, including:
`$ pip install lalsuite`
on visual studio and on anaconda.
i have also tried installing the wheel file found on https://pypi.org/project/lalsuite/#files but it wont install. is there someone with knowledge of python package installation or wheel who can help me?

Comment: What errors are you getting when attempting the installs?  Are you sure the pip you're using coincides with the python version you're running?  Is python3 the only python on the system, or is there a python2 lingering around?

Comment: Windows, I suppose? `lalsuite` provides a lot of wheels for Linux and MacOS, but not for w32, and no source code.

Comment: @phd wait so this means lalsuite is only supported on linux or macOS, so not in windows?

Comment: No idea. The source code is at https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/lalsuite but I don't see any installation instructions. And their GitLab is SO SLOOOOW I stopped looking into it.

Comment: @fubar im sure pip is not the problem as installation of other packages is causing no problem whatsoever

Comment: taking a quick look at the address you supplied, it appears that it's designed for SL6 ([Scientific Linux](https://scientificlinux.org)).  For Windows it seems to be recommending installing virtualbox and using a LIGO virtual machine... or that's how I took it upon seeing [this](https://computing.docs.ligo.org/daswgweb/download/vminstall.html) page.  You may be better off going on that tack rather than trying to force it onto a Windows platform, if you're able.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of details on your system, so I will assume you're running windows based on the comments.

Lalsuite is a software used for gravitational wave data analysis and only runs on macOS and Linux. The work around for Windows users is usually to use an online jupyter notebook/linux server or setup a virtual machine.

- The easiest method of using an online jupyter notebook is to setup a
  google colab account and install lalsuite. https://colab.google/
- To setup a virtual machine, see the windows subsystem for linux as the simplest method to my knowledge. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install. One may encounter issues like it simply not working, or having to install additional linux modules to recover the ability to easily visualise plots or run GUI applications.

Comment: Right now Google Colab is a sorely outdated fork of very old Jupyter that has been highly customized. It's indeed a good option as long as Google keeps offering it but for learning to work with modern Jupyter it is presently not the best choice unless they update it soon. The easiest method to use modern Jupyter online is via MyBinder-served sessions because you don't even need to login and it is very current. Indeed [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/35a72862c8be13dee31b61ebac2d9786) is one of the most cutting-edge options. For a less cutting-edge session, go to ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and press '`launch binder`' to launch a temporary anonymous session. You can make your own repo to set things up so in the resulting session things will be installed via various [configuration options](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/config_files.html). The computational power though may not cover what you need. Additionally because they are temporary and anonymous you need to be careful to save things back to your local machine often.